# Kotlin multiplatform macosArm64 "Execution failed for task ':commonizeNativeDistribution'"

Tags: xcode, macos, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

There is an [example](https://github.com/kepocnhh/xfiles-cli/tree/ed974307973653d3cc4fbb0708c6b9c269a10980) Kotlin Multiplatform code. When I use [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/release-notes.html), the task `gradle macos:runDebugExecutableMacosArm64` in the Terminal completes successfully and prints "Hello macos-arm64 native!".

When I try to compile the code into IntelliJ IDEA, the error is printed:

```
Execution failed for task ':commonizeNativeDistribution'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':kotlinKlibCommonizerClasspath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-klib-commonizer-embeddable:1.9.10 because no repositories are defined.
```

IDEA doesn't even want to accept the build script (everything is highlighted in red).

However, if you remove `macosArm64()` from the targets and add, for example, `jvm()`, then the IDEA will take the build script.

My question is what is missing from IDEA to process the build script, and why does this code work without IDEA?

```
Mac OS X 14.1 aarch64
Xcode 15.0.1 Build version 15A507
Gradle 8.4
Kotlin 1.9.10
JVM 17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.2+8-86)
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 (Community Edition) Build #IC-232.10203.10, built on October 24, 2023
```

Edit #1

[Fleet](https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/) gives the same error when trying to build the project.

[image: fleet error]

Answer (score 0):

The plugin "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", which I connect to internal modules, dynamically creates a `commonizeNativeDistribution` task in the root module. It does not appear in the list of tasks using the gradle tasks command.

This task tries to download a dependency for itself using the settings of the root module. And not the internal one, who was the initiator and who has the repository indicated, from where he took the plugin. And, apparently, he does it lazily. IDEA knows this and makes sure to run this task as part of the build of all project build scripts. Any way of specifying the `mavenCentral()` repository in the root module (NOT in the `buildScript` block) solves this problem.